# How to test my app in Android 2.3.5?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to check my application works fine or not in android 2.3.5 , but there is no SDK for 2.3.5 available in android developer site. How can i stimulate my app in android 2.3.5 , whether any third party tool is there or these version is equal to any other 2.3 series versions.

If any one knows help me out.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can test your app with android 2.3.4(API level 10).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, Android version 2.3.3 -> 2.3.7 are the same, just some really small minor changes.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Comment: it's the same as 2.3.3. But Android source (framework...) somewhat little differs.

Comment: Basically, they are not the same. Currently, I have an issue with Android v2.3.5 which doesnt move the database or doesnt open it, not sure it, while all other 2.3.3 devices work fine

Comment: @m.othman Did you ever figure out what is going on with the 2.3.5 bug of the database? I seem to be running into the same issue and cannot figure out why copying the database from the assets to the phone is not working or why the information being copied to the database is not accessible.

Comment: @DMan: I am may be too late to answer, the issue was due to the SQLite old version I used to build the database with. However, I had to recreate it with SQLite version 3.7.11  and now it is working fine. I managed to debug the app with actual device that run Android 2.3.5

Answer (score 1):

Arabic shaping is not fully supported in 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

I managed to debug the app with actual device that run Android 2.3.5 using eclipse